# Error accessing Twitter API endpoint: Limited access to v1.1 and v2 endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-oauth, endpoint

I'm trying to retrieve tweets containing a specific hashtag using the `twit` library in JavaScript. However, I'm encountering an error related to limited access to certain Twitter API endpoints. The error message I'm receiving is:
`You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g., media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product`

**Here's the code I'm using:**

```
const Twit = require('twit');

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

// Twitter API credentials (replace with your own)

const T = new Twit({

  consumer_key: 'YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY',

  consumer_secret: 'YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET',

  access_token: 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',

  access_token_secret: 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'

});

// Search parameters

const hashtag = '#Example';

const count = 100; // Number of tweets to retrieve

// Search tweets containing the hashtag

T.get('search/tweets', { q: hashtag, count }, (err, data) => {

  if (err) {

    console.error('Error:', err);

    return;

  }

  

  const tweetLinks = data.statuses.map(tweet => `https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name}/status/${tweet.id_str}`);

  

  // Create a new worksheet

  const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet([tweetLinks]);

  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Tweet Links');

  

  // Save the Excel file

  XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'tweetLinks.xlsx');

  

  console.log('Excel file generated with tweet links.');

});
```

I believe the error is related to the endpoint I'm trying to access. How can I resolve this issue and gain access to the necessary Twitter API endpoint to retrieve the tweets I need? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:

I'm using the twit library in Node.js to interact with the Twitter API.

I have checked my Twitter API credentials, and they seem to be correct.

I'm specifically trying to retrieve tweets with a certain hashtag: #Example.

By providing a clear title and a detailed explanation of your issue along with the code you're using, you're more likely to receive accurate and helpful responses from the Stack Overflow community.

I am confused what to do at this point and i am expecting a solution for my error

Comment: I'm not saying this is it but the Twitter API has been giving misleading/nongermane error messages for months. I wouldn't be surprised if this were a similar instance.

Comment: @DennisHackethal so there is no other way to extract tweets with the specific hashtag other than Twitter api?

Comment: that's a non sequitur

Comment: @Akcrazytech1 Error message clearly says that you don't have the necessary access level. Is there something wrong with getting it? Have you tried doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow up with Twitter API documentation here [enter link description here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api)

v1.1 has been deprecated (removed), and if there is no alternative API available in v2, you can't really access it without Enterprise API access.

Btw, the Enterprise API access is 42000 USD per month, no consumption based model.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also Getting the same Problem of

```
{"message":"You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product","code":453}
```

And After Reading the [Twitter (X) Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api) the only answer is to use the BASIC and PRO Level Access to get the data of tweets.

There is no other way!